# Using java applet in c++ program

Tags: java, c++

I am doing a project in c++ where I need to embed a java applet/java program.( like we usually see on webpages). I was wondering what is the easiest way to do this. Right now, I am using Qt designer. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are using Qt, have you considered QtWebkit?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [QWebPage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebpage.html) in your application you can `load` a url that has the `JApplet` embedded.

**Edit:**

You may not have JRE installed on the target machine if it's not loading the applet. If you do something like below it should spit out a message if something goes wrong with Java. This is just an untested example to give you the basic idea of what I meant.

An example webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Java Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="YourApplet.class" width=400 height=400>Java not supported or not installed</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Save this as `MyPageName.html`

A simplistic example of using this in Qt:

```
// the QWebView has a QWebFrame and QWebPage to make it easy
QWebView* webView = new QWebView(parentWidget); // MainWindow or whatever as parent
webView->load(QUrl("MyPageName.html")); // local page or valid URL
webView->show();
```

Hope that helps a bit more

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it but it doesn't work. It loads everything except the applet.

Comment: @nate Updated my answer to have more detail

Answer (score 1):

In version 4.8 of Qt, [java applets are not supported.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum)